# How to toggle flashlight mode?

Tags: java, android, flashlight

I want to add a button (which I have included in my activity_main) to my app that will launch a strobe effect when pressed and will stop when pressed again. I do not care about the speed, just that it toggles flash_mode_torch and flash_mode_off repeatedly until the button is pressed again.

I have tried:

- Using a handler
- Creating a separate class

The separate class containing the handler did not work because there was no intent in the main activity to launch or in the manifest because the code for it is not finished because I want to ask here how its done in the most simplest manner possible.

Comment: And how or why did it not work?

Comment: My updated description states why. This shouldn't be that complicated yet there isn't an answer on Google or Stackoverflow that clearly defines a strobe method.

Comment: https://github.com/stwalkerster/strobelight might be helpful

Comment: Hard to tell why it did not work if we don't see what you did.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

StrobeLightConfig.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.hardware.Camera;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.SeekBar;
    import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

    public class StrobeLightConfig extends Activity {

        boolean check = false;

        Camera sandy;
        StrobeRunner runner;
        Thread bw;
        ImageButton btnClick;

        public final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

        public final Runnable mShowToastRunnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

            }
        };

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            btnClick = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSwitch);


            runner = StrobeRunner.getInstance();
            runner.controller = this;

            if (runner.isRunning) {

            } else {
                try {
                    sandy = Camera.open();

                    if (sandy == null) {
                        return;
                    }

                    sandy.release();
                } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                    return;
                }
            }

            bw = new Thread(runner);
            bw.start();

            btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (check) {
                        bw = new Thread(runner);
                        bw.start();
                        check = false;
                    } else {
                        check = true;
                        runner.requestStop = true;
                    }            
                }
            });

            final SeekBar skbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.SeekBar01);
            skbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                        boolean fromUser) {


                    runner.delay = 101 - progress;
                    runner.delayoff = 101 - progress;

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
    //        runner.requestStop = true;

            super.onStop();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //        super.onBackPressed();

            Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startActivity(startMain);

        }

    }
```

StrobeRunner.java

```
    import android.hardware.Camera;

public class StrobeRunner implements Runnable {

    protected StrobeRunner()
    {

    }

    public static StrobeRunner getInstance()
    {
        return ( instance == null ? instance = new StrobeRunner() : instance );
    }

    private static StrobeRunner instance;


    public volatile boolean requestStop = false;
    public volatile boolean isRunning = false;
    public volatile int delay = 10;
    public volatile int delayoff = 500;
    public volatile StrobeLightConfig controller;
    public volatile String errorMessage = "";

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(isRunning)
            return;

        requestStop=false;
        isRunning = true;

        Camera cam = Camera.open();

        Camera.Parameters pon = cam.getParameters(), poff = cam.getParameters();

        pon.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        poff.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);

        while(!requestStop)
        {
            try{
                cam.setParameters(pon);
                Thread.sleep(delay);
                cam.setParameters(poff);
                Thread.sleep(delayoff);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex)
            {

            }
            catch(RuntimeException ex)
            {
                requestStop = true;
                errorMessage = "Error setting camera flash status. Your device may be unsupported.";
            }
        }

        cam.release();

        isRunning = false;
        requestStop=false;

        controller.mHandler.post(controller.mShowToastRunnable);
    }

}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/SeekBar01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="100"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:progress="0"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         >
    </SeekBar>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/w_led_on"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: If you're gonna copy paste someone else's code from github, at least have the courtesy to give them credit